# AngularJS + Jasmine: How to start from fresh module for each spec in a test in suite

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

Here's my simple code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
  .value('SimpleValue', {
    aaa: '£££'
  });
```

and unit tests

```
describe('ttt', function() {

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  it('ttt', inject(function(SimpleValue) {
    expect(SimpleValue.aaa).toEqual('£££');
    SimpleValue.aaa = 4;
  }));

  it('ttt', inject(function(SimpleValue) { // This doesn't start fresh and fails
    expect(SimpleValue.aaa).toEqual('£££');
  }));

});

describe('ttt', function() { // Neither does this

  var SimpleValue;
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_SimpleValue_) {
    SimpleValue = _SimpleValue_;
  }));

  it('ttt', function() {
    expect(SimpleValue.aaa).toEqual('£££');
  });

});
```

That is not the behaviour I was expecting from `beforeEach(module('myApp'));`. What is the point of using `module('myApp')` before each spec when according to documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.module  it merely

> collects the configuration information which will be used when the injector is created by inject.

? I thought that it would reset `myApp` to start clean for each `it` block but it turns out it doesn't.

Can anyone shed some light on this? Please see a plunk:

http://plnkr.co/edit/xMmstHxL2prQukXpXYXm?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Services registered with `.value` don't get reset. I can't tell you why, but it does seem unexpected.

Register using `.factory` for example, and tests pass as expected.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
// .value('SimpleValue', {aaa: '£££'});
    .factory('SimpleValue', function () {
        return {aaa: '£££'}; 
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @user2943490 ! `.factory` does indeed work differently. Here's an updated plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/x5HRALxv5JerWGJBz7Ug?p=preview.

Answer (score 0):

The thing here is that in your first test you are modifying properties of an object. But it is important to realize that there is only one copy of this object in the whole system. Re-writing myApp slightly differently should make it more clear:

```
var simpleValue = {aaa: '£££'};
var app = angular.module('myApp', []).value('SimpleValue', simpleValue);
```

See, you were kind of assuming that this part of the script is executed as part of each spec, which is not the case (this fragment of the code is loaded into browser only once).

Hopefully this plunker makes the whole story clear: http://plnkr.co/edit/iLuIPaLyVFgzoTLygFz1?p=preview

Comment: But I am not telling this value service to return `simpleValue` object defined earlier. I am telling it to create brand new `{aaa: '£££'}` object and return it. Still cannot understand why this doesn't happen after `module('myApp')`.